# Firebase Authentication Error code : auth/app-not-authorized

Tags: javascript, authentication, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-hosting

I Used firebase authentication Sign in a user with an email address and password. I also enable email/password & i used firebase hosting.

It show

Error code >> auth/app-not-authorized

Massage >> This app, identified by the domain where it's hosted, is not authorized to use Firebase Authentication with the provided API key. Review your key configuration in the Google API console.

```
   firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword($('#username').val(),                  $('#password').val())
            .then(                     
            )
            .catch(function (error) {
                var errorCode = error.code;
                var errorMessage = error.message;            
        console.log(">>>"+errorCode+">>"+errorMessage);                 
            });
```

Comment: you using domains ?  firebase hosting ?

Comment: **Review your key configuration in the Google API console** The message is loud and clear!

Answer (score 1):

You must have added key restrictions on your browser API key. You need to go to the Google Cloud console and remove those restrictions.

Answer (score 0):

https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials/oauthclient/

```
Go to OAuth 2.0 client IDs > Web client (auto created by Google Service)
```

and add your full domain name

add with www and without www

-- www.yourdomanin.com

-- yourdomanin.com

[image]